# How to setup gg.classpath for Oracle goldengate BigQuery Adapter

Tags: java, oracle, google-bigquery, oracle-golden-gate

Im tryinig to configure the BigQuery adapter for Oracle golden gate (12c). But unfortunately Im not able to understand this `gg.classpath`. In the doc, they mentioned to download client Lib from the [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-bigquery/v2)

But it contains so many folders, I don't know what folder I can download and where to copy them.

Also we have download some JAR files, and put it a directory.

```
Next, download the following JARs from Maven Central, and then include them in the classpath for the BigQuery Handler:
```

Where I can put these JAR files?

Can someone give me an example to configure the `gg.classpath`

**Oracle doc link**: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/big-data/12.3.2.1/gadbd/using-bigquery-handler.html#GUID-A8426075-81E8-47AB-BA15-3C564751A490

**example gg.classpath**: `gg.classpath= /path_to_repository/bigquery/libs/*:/path_to_repository/bigquery/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leaving the answer here, so others can benefit from this.

```
-- Steps for manually build the jar files
-- Or download all the jar from the above link and skip all these steps.

apt install maven
git clone https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services.git
cd google-api-java-client-services/clients/google-api-services-bigquery/v2/1.29.2/
mvn clean install

-- Copy all the jar files to /opt/ogg/jar
mkdir -p /opt/ogg/jar
cp target/*.jar /opt/ogg/jar

-- We also need to download the following JARs from Maven Central
-- download path /opt/ogg/jar

api-common-1.6.0.jar
gax-1.28.0.jar
gax-httpjson-0.45.0.jar
google-auth-library-credentials-0.9.1.jar
google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.9.1.jar
google-cloud-bigquery-1.31.0.jar
google-cloud-core-1.35.0.jar
google-cloud-core-http-1.35.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson-1.23.0.jar
guava-25.1-jre.jar
threetenbp-1.3.6.jar
```

Or I have a zip file that contains all the necessary files. You can get it from the below link.
https://github.com/BhuviTheDataGuy/medium-blog-files/raw/master/golden-gate-bigquery/jar-files.zip

For more detailed Step by step Setup for Oracle to BigQuery, refer the below link.
https://medium.com/searce/sync-oracle-to-bigquery-with-golden-gate-bigquery-adapter-59991bbdb5e3

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jars file from maven as mentioned in the documentation. Once you have download the jar files you can place them in any directory of the server/machine where you have installed Oracle GoldenGate for BigData.  Lets say for example /u01/OGG. After that you can include that directory in the classpath as below.

Example:
gg.classpath=dirprm:/u01/OGG/jdk1.8.0_221/*:/u01/OGG/oci-java-sdk/lib/*:/u01/OGG/oci-java-sdk/third-party/lib/*:/u01/OGG/hdfs_jar/*:/u01/OGG/parquet_jar/*

In the above example i have downloaded OCI Handler, Parquet Handler and their dependency and placed them in path /u01/OGG/. Here handler_name is oci-java-sdk and parquet_jar.

Comment: yeah,
I did the same, and we can put all the jar files (built from maven and downloaded additional files) in a single folder and we can point it.